# How to hide shebang when generating HTML page from PHP script

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that is designed to be run from the command line (including as a CRON job) *or* a web browser.

To run it from the command line, I understand that I need to include the shebang
`#!/usr/bin/php`
as the first line of the file.

But this line then appears before the `<html>` element when the script renders as an HTML web page.

How can I hide the shebang when rendering the script as HTML?

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't use the exact same script for use in Apache and use in console.

If you really need or want to, you can remove the shebang and run the script with the interpreter.

Currently you must have something like

```
* * * * * * userxy /folder/script.php
```

You can run it without shebang:

```
* * * * * * userxy php /folder/script.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'd be interested to hear what you would consider best practice, as I'd understood that the general rule was to keep duplication of code to a minimum.

Comment: @ms609 this rule is used wayyyy toooo strict. There are many cases where redundancy is a good solution. Ok the best practice would be to have 2 different files to begin with, one for console, one for Apache. Then you have a 3rd file which you just include so the both entry files can share the "main code" :-)

Answer (score 3):

> To run it from the command line, I understand that I need to include the shebang #!/usr/bin/php as the first line of the file.

No, you don't need to include a shebang line.
A shebang line tells the shell what program to use to run the script and, in order to work, needs the file to be marked as executable. The advantage is that it can be run in a standalone manner:

```
$ ./script.php
```

You can always run a PHP script by passing it as the argument to the PHP interpreter:

```
$ php script.php
```

The script file does not need to be executable and you can add more arguments to the PHP interpreter, if you need (f.e. e custom `php.ini` file).